# Show the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}|x|^x, &x\neq0 \\ 1, &x=0\end{cases}$ is not differentiable at zero.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

By the definition of differentiability, we need to show the following limit doesn't exist:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{|x|^x-1}{x}}$$
I've shown $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}{|x|^x}=1$, but couldn't proceed since L'Hospital's rule can't be used (cannot differentiate |x| since it is not differentible at $x=0$).
Is there any smarter way to find this limit?

Comment: @Khosrotash why is there a problem for $x<0$?

Comment: Inspired by Olivier's solution below, perhaps you could show that the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{|x|^x-1-x\log|x|}{x} = 0$$ if you wanted to resort to avoid series somehow. This would show the limit in question definitely doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one knows that
$$
e^u=1+u+O(u^2), \qquad u \to0,
$$ then one may write
$$
|x|^x=e^{x\ln|x|}=1+x\ln|x|+O(x^2\ln^2|x|),\qquad x\to 0,
$$ giving

> $$
> \frac{|x|^x-1}{x}=\ln|x|+O(x\ln^2|x|),\qquad x\to 0,
> $$

the conclusion being direct.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{|x|^x-1}{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e^{x\ln |x|}-1}{x\ln |x|}}\ln |x|=\lim_{x\to0}\ln |x|$$
where $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x\ln|x|=0$.